# Snow Leopard, Active Directory : cannot save a file, but 'save as' is working

Tags: snow-leopard

I'm using my Mac to connect to an Active Directory drive.

When I was running on Leopard, it worked fine : I could open, modify and save files from the remote drive.

Last week I upgraded my computer to Snow Leopard (10.6.7) and since that, I'm having problems : I still can connect to the remove drives, I can open files, but when I want to save them I get the following error : "`The document mydoc.txt could not be saved.`"

But if I do `Save as` and save the document under the very same name, then, it's working !

I have no idea what's wrong ! I tried to disconnect from the domain and reconnect, but I still have the problem.

Comment: Do you have an ACL on that folder?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to the problem :

The path to the document was the following :

```
smb://srv-fichiers1/Personnel/myhome/mydoc.txt
```

The problem was that I didn't have read/write access to the `Personnel` folder.

The administrator added read/write access to this folder and now, everything is working fine.

I agree that this is more a workaround than a real solution, but it does the trick for me !

Answer (score 0):

I saw this posted on a Mac and Windows interop site, 
[Snow Leopard and Active Directory Tips and Reports](http://www.macwindows.com/snowleopardAD.html#121009a)
[Try the following from the article](http://www.macwindows.com/snowleopardAD.html#121009a):

> Solution: In a long session of trial and error, I tried saving to the administrative C$ share on my Windows 7 desktop, which was owned by "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller". Creating a share on Win 7 had the same error behavior as before, when the shared folders owner was changed to TrustedInstaller, it worked fine. The following challenge was to port that solution to a XP/2003 environment, which doesn't have that account. My boss, out of a leap of logic, tried the "NETWORK SERVICE" domain account as the owner of the folder on 2003, and everything works. Obviously the sharing/ntfs permissions have to be set properly on top of that. I'm sure I'm not the only one that's had this problem, so I figured I'd toss it at you guys.

Weird.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried the solution mentionned, but the problem remains.